# Populate UITableView with NSDictionary JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am Fresher.I called API and i am getting request and Response of data.But,I dont know how to populate data from NSDictionary to TableviewCell.Can anyone help me.

Code is here:

```
var responseData:NSString =NSString(data:data!,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

println("Response Data is "+responseData)
var error: NSError?

let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

println("NSDictionary JSON Is",jsonData)

var error1: NSError?

var dict: NSDictionary =["Book_name":" "]
}
}
```

My Response Data is :

```
Response Data is {"ListOfBooks":[{"Book_name":"javascript_tutorial"}]}

(NSDictionary JSON Is, [ListOfBooks: ({"Book_name" = "javascript_tutorial";
    }
   )])
```

How to List the file name "javascript_tutorial" into tableview ?

Comment: u r getting array also inside the array u get the book name so add the array also

Comment: Ya,i tried to convert NSDictionary to Array.But,I am getting some error .Can u suggest me .How to do it ?

Comment: var results: NSArray = jsonData["ListOfBooks"] as NSArray. Try this you will get Bookname inside Nsarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

if jsonData {
// process jsonData

var arrayofBOOKs: NSArray = jsonData["ListOfBooks"] as NSArray
for elem: AnyObject in arrayofBOOKs {
let name = elem["Book_name"] as String

println("Book_name: \(name)")
// here add the string to array 
 items.addObject(name)
}
tableView.reloadData

} else {
// couldn't load JSON, look at error
}
```

Here are the steps to follow:

**Step-1**

Open the `ViewController.swift` class and add a new tableview instance variable below the class declaration

```
@IBOutlet
var tableView: UITableView!
```

**Step-2**

To conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` `protocol` just add them seperated by colons afterUIViewController in the class declaration

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var  items = NSMutableArray()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


}
```

**step-3**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text =  items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Comment: How to list Book_name into Tableviewcell ?.Can u suggest me?

Comment: what the result u get here println("Book_name: \(name)")

Comment: Book_name: Java - Abstraction
Book_name: Java - Basic Operators
Book_name: Java - Encapsulation
Book_name: Java - Inheritance
Book_name: Java - Multithreading Programming Tutorial
Book_name: Java - Polymorphism

Comment: i am getting  Book_name: Java - Abstraction