# How can I load tableView from an NSDictionary in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

I had an application in which I had a response like:

```
{
    "16-06-2016" = (
        {
            cccc = 16;
            dddd = 17;
        }
    );
    "17-06-2016" = (
        {
            cccc = 14;
            dddd = 19;
        },
        {
            cccc = 1;
            dddd = 9;
        }
    );
    "18-06-2016" = (
        {
            cccc = 14;
            dddd = 19;
        },
        {
            cccc = 1;
            dddd = 9;
        }
    );
}
```

How will I display this `NSDictionary` in my `UITableView`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what you want to show in uitable view?

Comment: Since cells are referenced by row number, I suggest the first step is to extract the items you want to display into an array.

Comment: there is already a topic. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28853406/5332195 check this out

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
self.sectionArr = [jsonDic allKeys]; //First get all section from dictionary like this
```

Now implement `TableView` delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return self.sectionArr.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.sectionArr objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     NSArray *arr = [jsonDic objectForKey:[self.sectionArr objectAtIndex:section]];
     return arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell= [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
     NSArray *arr = [jsonDic objectForKey:[self.sectionArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
     cell.textLabel.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"dddd"];
     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSArray *arr = [jsonDic objectForKey:[self.sectionArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
     NSLog(@"Selected Obj - %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"dddd"]);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And again, this solution fixes NSDictionary order issues a bit, but if data could be reloaded (say web request, or state restoration) keys order may change. Why nobody suggest sorting data first?

Comment: @hacker sort your `sectionArr` every time before reload `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

When I display an NSDictionary in a UITableView, since delegate methods like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` uses indexes, I typically do something like this to get an item at a particular index:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // Get array of keys
  NSArray *keys = [self.dictionary allKeys];
  // Get key for the current row
  NString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // Get object for current row
  id object = [self.dictionary objectForKey:key];

  // Then do the typical stuff
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ....
```

Though, in your case, "object" is an NSDictionary, so do something like this:

```
  ...
  // Get object for current row
  NSDictionary *item = [self.dictionary objectForKey:key];
  id cccc = [item objectForKey:@"cccc"];
  id dddd = [item objectForKey:@"dddd"];
  ....
```

If you need the keys sorted, then use `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` rather than `allKeys`.

Comment: This is a terrible advice, NSDictionary keys are not ordered!

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii, i mention the option for sorting keys. You're assuming OP wants the data sorted, yet they didn't define sort order in question.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii, this is a programmer question and answer site, not a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

(I put data you've provided into *dict* variable)

```
@interface MainViewController () {
    NSDictionary *dict;
    NSArray *sortedKeysAsSectionNames;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dict = @{@"16-06-2016": @[@{@"cccc": @(16), @"dddd": @(17)}],
             @"17-06-2016": @[@{@"cccc": @(14), @"dddd": @(19)},
                              @{@"cccc": @(1), @"dddd": @(9)}],
             @"18-06-2016": @[@{@"cccc": @(14), @"dddd": @(19)},
                              @{@"cccc": @(1), @"dddd": @(9)}]
             };

    NSArray *dictKeys = [dict allKeys];
    sortedKeysAsSectionNames = [dictKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        format.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
        NSDate *date1 = [format dateFromString:(NSString *)obj1];
        NSDate *date2 = [format dateFromString:(NSString *)obj2];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sortedKeysAsSectionNames.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [(NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:sortedKeysAsSectionNames[section]] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id key = sortedKeysAsSectionNames[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *dataInSectionArray = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSDictionary *dataForCellDict = [dataInSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForCellDict objectForKey:@"cccc"] description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[dataForCellDict objectForKey:@"dddd"] description];

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sortedKeysAsSectionNames[section];
}
```